# Flutter - Expanded only expanded height

Tags: flutter, dart

I think that I misused the `Expanded` component. I'd like it to take the whole widht available, but it did take the height.

This is what I get (the Checkout Button), with the debug mode enabled  :

[image]

Here's the code, and what I did :

```dart
Container(                          
 decoration: cardDecoration,
 child: Column(
   children: <Widget>[
     Expanded(
       child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top : 10.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){},
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: 
                  BorderRadius.only(
                   bottomLeft : Radius.circular(20.0), 
                   bottomRight : Radius.circular(20.0)
                  )
                 ),
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: Text(
                  'Check out'.toUpperCase(),
                   style: TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.white, 
                 ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   )
)
```

Comment: did you manage to figure out how to make the button in your last question?

Comment: Not really, I tried but didn't suceed. This is a reformulation of the problem

Comment: I had made a graphic for you but the post was deleted, looks like you've made some progress anyway https://i.imgur.com/HUYaBbO.png

Comment: Yaaaaay ! That was definitely it !! Thank you soooo much for your graphic and your help !

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Container(width: double.infinity,`

This should work hopefully without throwing any overflow errors (see graphic)

Answer (score 2):

I put here your graphic, it will surely help others !

[image]

Here's my result :

[image]

Thank you F-1 !

Comment: Glad I could help, the app looks very nice