# Flutter: Expand only the height of child widget in Row

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app with a drawer. At the top, it displays the username of the currently logged in user, and there is a button on the right the user can tap to log out.

I want the logout button to be a specific width, and for the username to take up the rest of the width. But, I also want to **expand the height of the logout button** to use up the rest of the height of the row, to maximize the area the user can tap to log out.

I have made the username display light green and the logout button gray so it is easy to see the size of each:

[image]

Basically, I want to remove that whitespace above and below the gray logout button, so it is all gray, so it is all tappable.

Expanding the username display and making the button wider is no problem, but how can I expand the button height to use all of the remaining height?

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 20,
            horizontal: 12,
          ),
          child: Text('test@example.com'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        minimumSize: const Size(0, 0),
        // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Container(
        // height: double.infinity,
        child: Icon(Icons.logout),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

As you can see from `// height: double.infinity,`, I already tried putting it into a container with infinite width (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787635/flutter-expanded-only-expanded-height), though that question was somewhat different), but that just caused a `BoxConstraints forces an infinite height` error. Maybe it's because this is all inside of a ListView() widget?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to set the `Row`'s height,

you could wrap `Row` widget with `IntrinsicHeight`.

Then set the height of the button to `double.infinity`.

```dart
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ...,
      ),
      TextButton(
        ...,
        child: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          ...,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

However, since `IntrinsicHeight` needs to be calculated before rendering,

care should be taken when using it for heavy widgets.

Please refer to the link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Si5XJ_IocEs